# How can i parse this JSON feed in Titanium Mobile App

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

How can i parse this JSON feed in Titanium Mobile App .

```
{
    "data":{
        "mat_78":{
            "id":"78",
            "title":"latest title here",
            "teaser":"latest teaser here",
            "body":"latest body here",
            "logo":"http://sites/default/files/6_0.jpg",
            "files":{
                "323":{
                    "fid":"323",
                    "filename":"joudi1m.jpg",
                    "tumb":"http://sites/default/files/joudi1m_0.jpg",
                    "large":"http://sites/default/files/joudi1_0.JPG",
                    "caption":"joudi1m.jpg"
                },
                "471":{
                    "fid":"471",
                    "filename":"Shot-(0_00_15_09)m.jpg",
                    "tumb":"http://sites/default/files/Shot(0_00_15_09)m.jpg",
                    "large":"http://sites/default/files/Shot(0_00_15_09).jpg",
                    "caption":"Shot(0_00_15_09)m.jpg"
                }
            }
        },
        "mat_79":{
            "id":"79",
            "title":"latest title 2 here",
            "teaser":"latest teaser 2 here",
            "body":"latest body 2 here",
            "logo":"http://sites/default/files/d09a0498a8512.jpg",
            "files":{
                "339":{
                    "fid":"339",
                    "filename":"BO1m.png",
                    "tumb":"http://sites/default/files/BO1_0.png",
                    "large":"http://sites/default/files/BO4_0.PNG",
                    "caption":"BO1m.png"
                },
                "340":{
                    "fid":"563",
                    "filename":"Slide9m.jpg",
                    "tumb":"http://sites/default/files/Slide9m.jpg",
                    "large":"http://sites/default/files/Slide9.JPG",
                    "caption":"Slide9m.jpg"
                }
            }
        },
        "mat_link":"mysite.cim/"
    }
```

this is my code segment to parse the JSON . Bu its not getting .... its giving me 'undefined'

```
var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    loader.open("GET","http://mysite.com/data_iphone/en&lmt=5");    
    loader.onload = function() 
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseData);
        Ti.API.debug(data); 
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
        var my_id = data[i].id; // id
        var my_title = data[i].title; // title
        Ti.API.debug(my_title); 
        }
    }

......
.........
```

Comment: What gives you undefined? var data ?

Comment: not var data ... Ti.API.debug(my_title);

Comment: are you accessing it correctly? First try to debug `data[i]`, then `data[i].mat_78.id` like this...

Answer (score 5):

I believe it should be more like this

```
    // NOTICE EXTRA "data" on end, if you are using JSON.parse()
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText).data;

    Ti.API.debug(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var my_id = data[i].id; // id
        var my_title = data[i].title; // title
        Ti.API.debug(my_title); 
    }
```

Comment: To clarify for others that might find this. The extra "data" on the end is the root node in the JSON data posted above. Adding the extra data accesses the rest of the object and allows for `data[i].title` instead of requiring `data.data[i].title`.

Answer (score 0):

use onload function for parse jason from yor server

```
var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
var requstUrl = "your url";
loader.open("GET", requstUrl);
loader.onload = function() {


    var daysh = eval('(' + this.responseText + ')');
    var status = daysh.status;
    var jsonArry = daysh.locations;
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonArry.length; i++)
    {

        alert(i);

    }


};
loader.send();
```

Comment: Maybe include a link to your fb page?  Or even better, include the information.

Comment: Avoid using eval function... its the lowest amonst all . Use it only extreme cases.